Snowflake Cortex LLM functions throwing error
I'm trying to run a Streamlit app to make a chatbot using Snowflake Cortex LLM function. Apparently there is an access problem with the llm functions.
This is the error I'm getting.
SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b63b07-0204-47c5-0002-24b6002bb7c2: 100351 (P0000): Request failed for external function COMPLETE$V2 with remote service error: 400 '"unknown model "mixtral-8x7b"" '; requests batch-id: 01b63b07-0204-47c5-0002-24b6002bb7c2:1:1:0:0; request batch size: 1 rows; request retries: 0; response time

import streamlit as st # Import python packages
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
session = get_active_session() # Get the current credentials

import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("max_colwidth",None)

### Default Values
#model_name = 'mistral-7b' #Default but we allow user to select one
num_chunks = 3 # Num-chunks provided as context. Play with this to check how it affects your accuracy
slide_window = 7 # how many last conversations to remember. This is the slide window.
#debug = 1 #Set this to 1 if you want to see what is the text created as summary and sent to get chunks
#use_chat_history = 0 #Use the chat history by default

### Functions

def main():
    
    st.title(f":speech_balloon: Chat Document Assistant with Snowflake Cortex")
    st.write("This is the list of documents you already have and that will be used to answer your questions:")
    docs_available = session.sql("ls @docs").collect()
    list_docs = []
    for doc in docs_available:
        list_docs.append(doc["name"])
    st.dataframe(list_docs)

    config_options()
    init_messages()
     
    # Display chat messages from history on app rerun
    for message in st.session_state.messages:
        with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
            st.markdown(message["content"])
    
    # Accept user input
    if question := st.chat_input("What do you want to know about your products?"):
        # Add user message to chat history
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": question})
        # Display user message in chat message container
        with st.chat_message("user"):
            st.markdown(question)
        # Display assistant response in chat message container
        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
            message_placeholder = st.empty()
    
            question = question.replace("'","")
    
            with st.spinner(f"{st.session_state.model_name} thinking..."):
                response = complete(question)
                res_text = response[0].RESPONSE     
            
                res_text = res_text.replace("'", "")
                message_placeholder.markdown(res_text)
        
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": res_text})


def config_options():


    
    st.sidebar.selectbox('Select your model:',(
                                    'mixtral-8x7b',
                                    'snowflake-arctic',
                                    'mistral-large',
                                    'llama3-8b',
                                    'llama3-70b',
                                    'reka-flash',
                                     'mistral-7b',
                                     'llama2-70b-chat',
                                     'gemma-7b'), key="model_name")
                                           
    # For educational purposes. Users can chech the difference when using memory or not
    st.sidebar.checkbox('Do you want that I remember the chat history?', key="use_chat_history", value = True)

    st.sidebar.checkbox('Debug: Click to see summary generated of previous conversation', key="debug", value = True)
    st.sidebar.button("Start Over", key="clear_conversation")
    st.sidebar.expander("Session State").write(st.session_state)


def init_messages():

    # Initialize chat history
    if st.session_state.clear_conversation or "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = []

    
def get_similar_chunks (question):

    cmd = """
        with results as
        (SELECT RELATIVE_PATH,
           VECTOR_COSINE_SIMILARITY(docs_chunks_table.chunk_vec,
                    SNOWFLAKE.CORTEX.EMBED_TEXT_768('e5-base-v2', ?)) as similarity,
           chunk
        from docs_chunks_table
        order by similarity desc
        limit ?)
        select chunk, relative_path from results 
    """
    
    df_chunks = session.sql(cmd, params=[question, num_chunks]).to_pandas()       

    df_chunks_lenght = len(df_chunks) -1

    similar_chunks = ""
    for i in range (0, df_chunks_lenght):
        similar_chunks += df_chunks._get_value(i, 'CHUNK')

    similar_chunks = similar_chunks.replace("'", "")
             
    return similar_chunks


def get_chat_history():
#Get the history from the st.session_stage.messages according to the slide window parameter
    
    chat_history = []
    
    start_index = max(0, len(st.session_state.messages) - slide_window)
    for i in range (start_index , len(st.session_state.messages) -1):
         chat_history.append(st.session_state.messages[i])

    return chat_history

    
def summarize_question_with_history(chat_history, question):
# To get the right context, use the LLM to first summarize the previous conversation
# This will be used to get embeddings and find similar chunks in the docs for context

    prompt = f"""
        Based on the chat history below and the question, generate a query that extend the question
        with the chat history provided. The query should be in natual language. 
        Answer with only the query. Do not add any explanation.
        
        <chat_history>
        {chat_history}
        </chat_history>
        <question>
        {question}
        </question>
        """
    
    cmd = """
            select snowflake.cortex.complete(?, ?) as response
          """
    df_response = session.sql(cmd, params=[st.session_state.model_name, prompt]).collect()
    sumary = df_response[0].RESPONSE     

    if st.session_state.debug:
        st.sidebar.text("Summary to be used to find similar chunks in the docs:")
        st.sidebar.caption(sumary)

    sumary = sumary.replace("'", "")

    return sumary

def create_prompt (myquestion):

    if st.session_state.use_chat_history:
        chat_history = get_chat_history()

        if chat_history != []: #There is chat_history, so not first question
            question_summary = summarize_question_with_history(chat_history, myquestion)
            prompt_context =  get_similar_chunks(question_summary)
        else:
            prompt_context = get_similar_chunks(myquestion) #First question when using history
    else:
        prompt_context = get_similar_chunks(myquestion)
        chat_history = ""
  
    prompt = f"""
           You are an expert chat assistance that extracs information from the CONTEXT provided
           between <context> and </context> tags.
           You offer a chat experience considering the information included in the CHAT HISTORY
           provided between <chat_history> and </chat_history> tags..
           When ansering the question contained between <question> and </question> tags
           be concise and do not hallucinate. 
           If you don´t have the information just say so.
           
           Do not mention the CONTEXT used in your answer.
           Do not mention the CHAT HISTORY used in your asnwer.
           
           <chat_history>
           {chat_history}
           </chat_history>
           <context>          
           {prompt_context}
           </context>
           <question>  
           {myquestion}
           </question>
           Answer: 
           """

    return prompt


def complete(myquestion):

    prompt =create_prompt (myquestion)
    cmd = """
            select snowflake.cortex.complete(?, ?) as response
          """
    
    df_response = session.sql(cmd, params=[st.session_state.model_name, prompt]).collect()
    return df_response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

(last retry): 22.54ms
I saw that LLM Cortex functions are not available for certain zones. Is there a way to verify if the error I'm getting is an access problem or should I fix something in the code?

400 generally indicates that resource that we are trying to reach is unavailable. error msg indicates the same too. To confirm we can try enabling cross region cortex and see if expected results are there.
If you are accountadmin by role, then can do
ALTER ACCOUNT SET CORTEX_ENABLED_CROSS_REGION = 'AWS_US'

source - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowflake-cortex/cross-region-inference

on other channels, I noticed people talking about reducing token size.
